# Value of a property in laravel 5.4's $request in multiple methods

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, get

I swear this was working yesterday, but for some reason today I'm getting a `null` value for an $email_token on my $request. I'm making a GET request to get the token and then attempting to use it in my POST to an api. Here are my methods:

```
public function getOptOut(EmailOptingRequest $request)
{
    $customer = Customer::find(Auth::id());
    $email = $customer['attributes']['Email'];
    $token = "552sg1fw485ww";

    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/api/Services/Email/Opting', [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
        ],
        'email' => $email
    ]);

    $emailToken = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true)[0]['token'];

    return view('customer.email-opting', array(
        'customer' => $customer,
        'email' => $email,
        'token' => $token,
        'client' => $client,
        'res' => $res,
        'emailToken' => $emailToken
    ));
}

public function postOptOut(EmailOptingRequest $request)
{
    $email_token = $request->emailToken;

    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.example.com/api/Services/Email/Opting', [
        'email_token' => $email_token,
        'marketing' => (int)$request->input('marketing', 0),
        'promotional' => (int)$request->input('promotional', 0),
        'news' => (int)$request->input('news', 0),
        'feedback' => (int)$request->input('feedback', 0)
    ]);

    return redirect('customer')->with('success', 'You will no longer receive email notifications from the categories you unchecked.');
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `$request` is actually an object and not null (`var_dump($request)`)? I think the issue here may be sitting deeper in your code from where `postOptOut` is called

Comment: what laravel version you are using ?

Comment: 5.4. It is an object full of lots of goodies, but not my token.

Comment: What do you get for `dd($request->all())`?

Comment: Looks like I'm just getting the session token: `array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "A34hfJPRxzsHccOiKA62Um0DDiwosp7eBft5n5MW"
]`

Comment: How is the information being submitted to the server?

Comment: Not sure I can answer that. It's a pretty standard laravel app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to pass the `$email_token` hidden in the form to access it on the $request.